# What is the work flow of ui component and block file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, xml, uicomponent

In Magento 2 UI components structure are bit difficult to learn and no more reference are found for clearly understand How to work with UI Components.

**My concern is that How block is dealing with Ui Component xml file.**

**How to define Relation between Block File and UI Components in Magento 2**

If somebody take any small example and explain the flow of that then i think it's really helpful for me.

Thanks in advanced